# How can I substitute images on Illustrator CC while mantaining the way they are laid out?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello I'm totally new on Illustrator but I've looked for this and didn't find anything.

I want to print an PnP game called Maximum Apocalypse, most of the files come on a 9 grid per page pattern but some others, as well as the backs, come alone in the center of a page.
I want, for example, to substitute every image on this file with a copy of the back image:
[image: File with the fronts of the cards]
File with the fronts of the cards

[image: I can move the image but can't substitute it, also please note how it has a weird un-selectable white frame, wich is in front of the images]
I can move the image but can't substitute it, also please note how it has a weird un-selectable white frame, wich is in front of the images

Also there is this super strange thing going on, the images all overlap each other but the program kind of splits the difference and creates a junction in the middle point, hiding the rest:
[image: You can see the overlapping and the way the difference is split]
You can see the overlapping and the way the difference is split

I don't even know what concept or tool to look for, maybe somebody can help me, what I want is to have a way to place this image on top or instead every card, while mantaining that weird split and white border and everithing, so I can print correctly, am I asking too much?
[image: Only the center part, wich I can select and copy no problemo, and also is the same size as the images I want to substitute]
Only the center part, wich I can select and copy no problemo, and also is the same size as the images I want to substitute

Please help me!! I've worked so damn hard for a month to translate this game to play with my friends, I've learned a lot along the way but this is a wall I can't pass.
Many thanks yous!

Comment: If they are raster images, you can relink them via the Links Panel in AI.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much Scott, I don't know how to upvote you but you have my eternal gratitude

Comment: Hi Adrian, I added an actual answer you can select as correct if this worked for you. I don't think you have enough reputation to up vote yet.

Answer (score 1):

If the images in question are all linked or embedded *raster* images... You can relink the images to another source by using the **Links Panel** (`Window > Links`) in Illustrator.

Simply highlight an image in the Links Panel and from the panel menu, choose `Relink...` then navigate to and select your replacement image. It's easiest if the replacement image is the same dimensions/resolution as the image to be replaced.